# 500. That’s an error. When i authenticate Google Assistant SDK to Server at very beginning

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Hi I am trying to build Google Assistant SDK on my PC Ubuntu 16.04.

At first,i follow this topic "Embed the Google Assistant" in "
Introduction to the Google Assistant Library" doc (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/) .

And then fully obey instructions from step 1~5, and i encounter an Server Error 500. That’s an error at this step 
"google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
      --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \
      --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json".
I use the client secrets downloaded from step4 "Register the Device Model" , but the error occurred. when i recreated a new project and redo all step again , its the same that the error 500,That's an error occurred at the same command.

I am from Taiwan, does it request to choose my current country at very beginning of creating project?(now i just use default "US") , or something i need to notice?

Jack Hsu

Comment: There's actually an issue in the project github for this at https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/277 What worked for me was a suggestion by one of the project collaborators to go into the Google Cloud Platform API Credentials and setup the OAuth consent screen: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent I don't recall seeing anything about this in the Google Assistant Library docs, but perhaps they'll add a blurb about it now that there's an issue on the project Github.

Comment: thanks for your help. after setup up oauth consent page. it works now. and yes they might blurb on it ^^